# How do I Customize JHipster code generation templates?

Tags: jhipster

I want to customize Jhipster code generation logic for Java where I want to call a custom audit trail service which is already developed by my organization. Whenever an entity is added/updated or deleted, I want to call that audit trail service.

Can I customize JHipster code generation so that I can modify the template which generates PUT/POST/DELETE methods for entity ? If I can modify that template and put my custom code, it will save me lot of work whenever new entities are generated.

I did not find good documentation on how to customize these templates. Can someone help?

regards,

Venky

Comment: Have you read the doc about blueprints? https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/creating-a-blueprint/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gael mentioned above: Blueprints are used to customizing the code generation. Its very nice and easy way to add custom code.